# Getting error (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a direct buffer) when starting an app that was fine this morning

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

So i had this app that was fine this morning but I deleted some files accidentally and I restored to previous version in local history, and to my surprise it gave me an error that wasn't giving me this morning, can you guys help me ?

My code is this :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new OrdersPagerAdapter(this));




    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(
            tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:{
                    tab.setText("Resumos");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_resumos);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    tab.setText("Favoritos");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fav);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    );
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();
}
```

}

And the error I'm getting is :

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pedrogouveia.resumos/com.pedrogouveia.resumos.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a direct buffer
```